# Perform some operation as soon as eth0 is up

Tags: networking, scripts

I have to perform a routine which requires eth0 to be up.
I have tried to put it into /etc/rc.local, anyway it could not be triggered as eth0 could have not been initialized yet.

Is there a way to attach to system's event dispatcher so to start a script just when eth0 is detected to be up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you must to place your script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` directory:

```
sudo cp /path/to/your_routine /etc/network/if-up.d/
```

Then add the following line after you defined `eth0` interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
post-up /etc/network/if-up.d/your_routine
```

where `post-up` command run command or shell script after bringing the interface `eth0` up (see `man interfaces` for more info - somewhere at the line 149).

Here is an example about how the `/etc/network/interfaces` file should look after you edited it:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
name Ethernet LAN card
address 192.168.10.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
network 192.168.10.0
gateway 192.168.10.254
post-up /etc/network/if-up.d/your_routine
# some more interfaces
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
# ...
```

After these changes, restart the networking service:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: Seems nice...but I can't see any reference to eth0 in your solution, will the routine be executed when every nic is initialized?

Comment: @Phate See that I just edited my answer.

Comment: @Phate I'm happy to hear that!